# Как проверить корректность скачанного файла?

Tags: c#

Раньше при скачивании я расчитывал, что сервер явно заявит о размере файла и всё будет хорошо:

```
  var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
  try
  {
    response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    result = await CopyTo(response.GetResponseStream());
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex) { }
  if (response.ContentLength == result.LongLength)
    return result;
  return null;
```

Недавно, сервер отдал отрицательный размер, и я понял что такая проверка никуда не годится. Как тогда проверять, а всё ли сервер отдал? Пока немного переделал:

```
  var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
  try
  {
    response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    result = await CopyTo(response.GetResponseStream());
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex) { }
  if (response.ContentLength <= result.LongLength)
    return result;
  return null;
```

Но теперь достоверность никакая, очевидно. Может есть какой то "правильный" способ, а я страдаю херней?

Почему я спрашиваю - иногда не случается никакого исключения, но файл оказывается недокачанный - сервера видимо не гарантируют полного скачивания и могут вернуть положительный ответ вместо ошибки. Проверка размера в такой ситуации спасала.

Comment: ну если сервер не предоставляет никаких метаданных, размер или, в идеале, хеш файла, то вариантов в общем то почти нет. Остается одна лазейка - если файл имеет собственные метаданные в заголовке внутри файла, тогда на основе этих внутренних данных иногда можно оценить целый файл или нет.

Comment: @rdorn у меня в основном картинки - Jpeg, gif, png. Явного размера в заголовках у всех похоже нет. В целом - печально. Спасибо.

Comment: @Monk, но все же можно рассчитать размер. Точно помню, что в `png` перед каждым чанком идёт его длина. В `gif` аналогично записаны размеры блоков и, если не изменяет память, даже размеры самого изображения (ширина и высота), так что рассчитать можно и из них. Вопрос лишь в том, стоит ли игра свеч ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov если ссылок подкинете по теме - мне пригодится.

Comment: @Monk, простенькая [статья про png на Хабре](https://m.habr.com/post/130472/), [ничего лишнего про gif](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html) (хД), [статья про jpeg на wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format)... Вот такие дела. В принципе, на английской вики часто прикладывают к описанию файла и структуру его заголовков, так что обо всех форматах можно почитать и там)