# Как проверить размер файла после загрузки?

Tags: c#

На сервере хранится файл определённого размера ( разный размер )

После загрузки ( по не правильной ссылке ) файл скачивается битым.

Можно ли сделать проверку после загрузки файла с размером на сервере ?

Если размер файла после загрузки не равен размеру файла на сервере, то удалить этот локальный файл.

Пример загрузки файла с сервера:

```
using (WebClient DownloadFile = new WebClient())
{
   DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);  
}
```

Может можно как-то проверить размер с помощью:

```
static public long GetFileSize(string url)
{
        using (WebClient obj = new WebClient())
        using (Stream s = obj.OpenRead(url))
            return long.Parse(obj.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"].ToString());
}
```

или

```
using (WebClient DownloadFile = new WebClient())
{
   DownloadFile.OpenRead(url);
   Int64 bytesTotal = Convert.ToInt64(DownloadFile.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);
 // И тут какая-нибудь проверочка 
}
```

Comment: Сервер один и тот же или разные? Некоторые сервера не отдают размер файла.

Comment: @Monk, Сервер разный

Comment: Собственно, был у меня такой же вопрос - нет на него нормального ответа. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675151/196257

Comment: GetFileSizeEx получает размер файла в 64-битную переменную. И я не верю что в божественном C# нет способа сделать то же самое

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @GooliveR Понятнее не стало. GetFileSizeEx как крайний случай получения размера файла вам уже приведен.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: В божественном C# размер файла получается как `new FileInfo(path).Length` (выдаёт `long`).