# C# TCP HTTP удостовериться что получил все данные

Tags: c#, http, tcp

Как узнать что по TCP получил все байты? Поверх TCP например HTTP/1.1 с keep-alive. Откуда сервер знает что получил все без закрытого соединения?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/plain 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

7\r\n
Mozilla\r\n 
9\r\n
Developer\r\n
7\r\n
Network\r\n
0\r\n 
\r\n
```

Comment: Content-Length же

Comment: @PavelMayorov ok, но я не понимаю сколько минимум байтов ждать

Comment: Единственный надёжный способ - сначала передать количество байт, потом - сами байты. В http это делается через заголовок content-length.

Comment: @PashaPash Content-Length: - количество байтов тела? после /r/n/r/n?

Comment: Некоторые сайты позволяют себе не передавать content-length (0), в итоге у них - видимо совсем никак.

Comment: @Monk если content-length нету, и это не chunked encoding - значит, надо читать до конца потока.

Comment: @Monk никакого "никак" тут быть не может

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда может подскажете в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675151/196257 как это сделать?

Comment: @Monk вы смешиваете две разные проблемы - определение границы ответа и его целостности

Comment: @PavelMayorov окей, согласен.

Answer (score 1):

В [RFC 7230 в разделе 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) детально описано, как определяется длина тела HTTP сообщения.

Вкратце алгоритм таков:

- Проверяем код ответа, если это специальный код - значит тела сообщения нет, его длина равна нулю
- Если есть заголовок `Transfer-Encoding` и в нем присутствует `chunked`, то используем `chunked`-кодировку, которая четко определяет конец потока. Описана в этом же [RFC, секция 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1)
- Смотрим на заголовок `Content-Length`. Если присутствует ровно один заголовок, значит читаем указанное количество байт
- Если это `request`-сообщение, и ничего из вышесказанного не сработало, то принимаем длину тела сообщения 0
- Если это `response`-сообщение, то читаем поток до закрытия соединения сервером

Понятно, что последний пункт не может работать для `Keep-Alive` соединения, поэтому обычно в вас будет присутствовать `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, реже `Content-Length`.

Comment: Content должен быть в виде чанков (пример добавил в вопрос)?

Comment: @MikeWaters да, это и есть он

Answer (score 0):

TCP это протокол транспортного уровня. Когда данные инкапсулируются в пакет для них вычисляется контрольная сумма, что гарантирует их целостность при получении. После получения пакета, получатель отправляет отправителю сообщение что данные получены. Если отправитель в течении определенного времени не получает подтверждение, то он отправляет пакет повторно.