# В момент перехода с HTTP на WebSocket браузер ждет чего-то еще после рукопожатия

Tags: php, websocket

Доброго времени суток всем.
Я хочу написать простой WebSocket сервер на php и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
При рукопожатии я отправляю ответ с сервера, согласно спецификации

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($server, '127.0.0.1', 8131);
socket_listen($server, 100);
socket_set_nonblock($server);   

$sockets = array();
while(true) {
    $sock = socket_accept($server);
    if ($sock !== false)
        $sockets[] = array($sock, false);

    if (!empty($sockets)) 
        foreach($sockets as $sock) {
            $data = @socket_read($sock[0], 1024);
            if ($data !== false) 
                if ($sock[1] == false)
                    $sock[1] = handshake($sock[0], $data);
                else 
                    обработка($sock[0], $data);
        }
}


function handshake($sock, $data) {
    $len = strlen('Sec-WebSocket-Key: ');
    $pos1 = strpos($data, 'Sec-WebSocket-Key:') + $len;
    $pos2 = strpos($data, "\r\n", $pos1 + 1);
    $Sec_WebSocket_Key = substr($data, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1);
    echo 'KEY: '.$Sec_WebSocket_Key.'<br>';

    $SecWebSocketAccept = base64_encode(  sha1($Sec_WebSocket_Key.'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', true)  );
    $answer = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ".$SecWebSocketAccept."\r\n\r\n";        

    socket_write($sock, $answer, strlen($answer));
    echo '<br>Ушло: '.$answer.'!<br><br><br>';  

    return true;
}


function обработка($sock, $data) {
    echo "Пришли данные: ".$data."<br>";

    socket_write($sock, $data." answer");
}
```

Немного извращенно местами.
Ключ из запроса извлекаю верно.
SecWebsocketAccept совпадает с примером из документации и кодируется, вроде, верно. 
Когда ответ с сервера приходит на клиент, то он как бы грузится. Т.е. происходит загрузка страницы и она не прекращается. Ошибок не выдает и ни одно из событий, навешанных на вебсокет не срабатывает. (если что-то поменять в ответе сервера, то в логах браузера будет выдавать либо некорректный ключ, либо лишние поля).

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://socket-example.ru:8131/index.php");
socket.open = function() { 
    alert("Соединение установлено"); }
socket.onerror = function() {
    alert("Ошибка при подключении сокета"); }
socket.onclose = function(e) {
    alert("Соединение закрыто." + e.message); print(e);}
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert("Получено сообщение: " + e.data); }
```

Никак не пойму, почему браузер не воспринимает присланный заголовок сервером и никак не хочет переходить с HTTP на WebSocket. Страница грузится и все тут.
Помогало оканчивать код командой socket_close(...); Но тогда выдает на клиенте, что соединение разорванно.

Также можете ответить, как в протоколе HTTP браузер узнает, что сообщение закончилось, кроме как разрывать соединение? Например, если приходит полностью пустая страница, состоящая только из HTTP заголовка.
Знаю, что используют Content-Length: 0, но есть ли еще способы?

Вышеприведенный код сервера новый и более понятный должен быть, есть еще старый (на нем почти все тестил) - может тоже даст что-то понять

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$answer = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
    //"Content-Length: 0\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ";

set_time_limit(17);
ob_implicit_flush();

$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($server, '127.0.0.1', 8131);
socket_listen($server, 100);// Socket listening... OK
//socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
echo "Сервер запущен!<br>";

$sock = NULL;
while(true) {

    $sock = socket_accept($server);
    echo "Есть подключение клиента!<br>";

    $data = socket_read($sock, 1024);
    echo "Пришло: ".$data."<br><br>";


    /*$data_arr = explode(' ', $data);
    foreach ($data_arr as $val)
        echo $val.'<br>';*/

    $len__1 = strlen('Sec-WebSocket-Key: ');
    $pos1 = strpos($data, 'Sec-WebSocket-Key:') + $len__1;
    $pos2 = strpos($data, "\r\n", $pos1 + 1);
    $Sec_WebSocket_Key = substr($data, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1);
    echo 'KEY: '.$Sec_WebSocket_Key.'<br>';


    $SecWebSocketAccept = base64_encode(  sha1($Sec_WebSocket_Key.'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', true)  );
    $answ = $answer.$SecWebSocketAccept."\r\n\r\n";//\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat



    socket_write($sock, $answ, strlen($answ));
    echo 'Ушло:<br>'.$answ.'!<br><br><br>';

    //socket_close($sock);
    $data = socket_read($sock, 1024);
    echo "Считал: ".$data."<br>";
    socket_write($sock, bindec(0)."myMSG".decbin(255));

    while(true);
    if ($data == 333) {
        echo "Сокет закрыт!<br>";
        break;
    }
}

socket_close($server);
```

Comment: Как вы запускаете этот код?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884843/c-tcp-http-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5/884888#884888 мой ответ в другом вопросе, по поводу того, как браузер узнает конец сообщения

Comment: andreymal, php скрипт запускаю путем захода на заданную ссылку в браузере (http://socket-example.ru). Клиентский - двойным кликом по html файлу в том же браузере.

Comment: Zergatul, Спасибо. А еще - не скажите, какой из этих описанных способов происходит в моём случае, а то 2 как минимум подходят...